# ProgressIndicator doesnt showed exactly in async function

Tags: c#, async-await, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

I'm new to WP. I try to show `ProgressIndicator` when loading data from Server and hide it when loading finished. However, I had a problem: "The `ProgressIndicator` only show when my `MessageBox` showed. Here's my code:

```
    private void MainPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create progress loading 
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Loading...";
        SyncDbIfNeed();
    }


    private void ShowHideProgressIndicator(Boolean isVisible)
    {
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = isVisible;
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = isVisible;
        Debug.WriteLine("ShowHide: " + isVisible);
    }


    private async void SyncDbIfNeed()
    {
        if (!MySettings.IsCategorySynced())
        {
            ShowHideProgressIndicator(true);
            try
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                String json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(MyConstants.UrlGetAllCategory);
                MessageBox.Show(json);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unexpected error");
            }
            ShowHideProgressIndicator(false);

        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain it, and give me an advice? Thanks.

Comment: Which MessageBox? There are way too many here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman   when MessageBox.Show(json) showed, the ProgressIndicator showed too. However, the indicator doesnt showed before MessageBox showed.

Answer (score 2):

`async void` methods should only be used for event handlers. Any other asynchronous method should return a `Task` or `Task<T>`.

You should also split UI loginc from non-UI logic.

Try this instead:

```
private async void MainPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Loading...";

    ShowHideProgressIndicator(true);

    try
    {
        var json = await SyncDbIfNeedAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unexpected error");
    }

    ShowHideProgressIndicator(false);
}

private void ShowHideProgressIndicator(Boolean isVisible)
{
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = isVisible;
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = isVisible;
    Debug.WriteLine("ShowHide: " + isVisible);
}


private async Task<string> SyncDbIfNeedAsync()
{
    if (!MySettings.IsCategorySynced())
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(MyConstants.UrlGetAllCategory);
        MessageBox.Show(json);
    }
}
```

To learn more about `async`-`await`, take a look at my [curah](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm reading your tut and will try your code later.